# Highcharts symbol not appearing in chart (opacity set to 0, it appears)

Tags: highcharts

I'm using HighCharts to display a couple of graphs on my Pregnancy Calculator. They were working perfectly until recently. Now, for some strange reason, the Symbol image of the teddy bear on the second chart is appearing (in the Highcharts code) as opacity:0 until you mouse over the space (at which point the teddy bear appears). I can't understand why it's suddenly doing this or seem to find a way to set it to opacity:1

https://www.thecalculatorsite.com/health/pregnancy-calculator.php

(you'll need to click 'calculate' and then scroll down to the second graph, marked as 'probability of birth by this day' - you'll see a gap in the graph where there isn't a green marker. The teddy bear symbol should be there, but isn't appearing until mouse-over).

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi @Alastair, Does this example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/zrp4tfdk/1/ present your problem? If you set opacity to 1 for normal state, it will work fine. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/zrp4tfdk/2/

Comment: Hi @ppotaczek - you've solved it. Thank you so much for your help. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set opacity to 1 for normal state:

```
  series: [{
    ...,
    data: [..., {
      y: 54.805615550756,
      marker: {
        ...,
        states: {
          normal: {
            opacity: 1
          }
        }
      }
    }, ...]
  }]
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/zrp4tfdk/2/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.data.marker.states.normal